# Check for a tag presense on the page with Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a page with next code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>smth</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="doc" class="searchN">
<div id="hd" style="border-bottom:0;">
    <a id="logo" class="logoN" href="/" alt="logo" title="open project"></a>

</div> 
    <div id="bd-cross">    
        <ol class="site" start=1>

            <li class="">
                <a href="url/">Smth</a>
                <div class="ref">
                <a href="News_and_Media/">Regional: Europe:</a>
          </div>    
            </li>

            <li class="">
                <a href="url2">Descr3</a> 
                <div class="ref">
                <a href="url3">Descr3</a>   
          </div>    
            </li>
....
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I need to check `<li class="">` tag presence at page. I use Python+RegExp:

```
import re
import urllib2
url = 'url'
#Parse it
MainPage = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
Li = re.findall("<div id=\"bd-cross\">*<li class=\"\">*</li>", MainPage)
try:
    if Li:
        print "Li tag on " +url+ ": Yes"
    else:
        print "Li tag on " +url+ ": No"
except:
    print "Error"
```

output is No but it should be Yes 'cause page contains it tag. If I print Li it output '[ ]'.

Comment: chuck norris *can* parse html with regex!

Comment: yep i've missed it in code. edit for now.

Comment: @root Jon Skeet can parse Chuck Norris's parsing of html with regex! But he chooses not to in order to prevent the Singularity from happening too early. It's all to do with Conservation of Awesomeness…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a package such as `BeautifulSoup` or `lxml.html.soupparser`, it will make your life much much easier. With the latter, you could do what you want as follows:

```
>>> import lxml.html.soupparser
>>> MainPage = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
>>> HtmlDoc = lxml.html.soupparser.fromstring(MainPage)
>>> Elements = HmtlDoc.xpath('//div[@id="bd-cross"]//li[@class=""]')
>>> if len(Elements) > 0:
>>>     print 'Yes'
>>> else:
>>>     print 'No'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't want to use an HTML parser like a BeautifulSoup, *and* assuming you have "bd-cross" div tag somewhere in the HTML that is not in your excerpt, my bet is that your regex is not looking across new-line boundaries.

In fact, you are missing the `.` character in your regex, so I would also suggest using a regex tester to verify your regex does what you think it should, such as [this one](http://regexpal.com/).

To fix this, add `flags=re.DOTALL` to the end of the `re.findall` function as another argument.

See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

> Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline.